# Coding an infinite number of inputs in python

Tags: python

I am coding a calculator in python. I have to receive many inputs from the user to calculate complex calculations.Now, I only have 2 inputs. How to code many/infinite no.of inputs from user?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your code in a while loop

```
while True:
  user_input = input()
  if user_input == "":
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to write the input into a while loop?

```
old_input = ''
while(True):
    number = input("Insert")
    operation = old_input + number
    print(operation)
    old_input = number
```

And then you can parse your operation string in order to make the operations